# Program to log of deleted files Windows 7 +

Tags: windows, log-analysis

I look for a program that save a **historical deleted files**

For example

```
|File----------|User----------|Delete Date--------|
 my.txt         Admin          03/24/2015
 file.rar       user           03/24/2015
 homework.doc   Admin          03/21/2015
```

Specs

- Must be run in Windows 7 or +
- Free is better
- Only deleted by user files may appear
- *File* and *Date* data must be show *User* can be optional

Comment: Why do you want this? Can't you use permissions to prevent the files from being overwritten or deleted? Also, in Explorer, users can recycle files or delete them directly. In other applications, they can also delete files permanently. Must you log all three of Explorer recycling, Explorer deletion, and external deletion? Please [edit] your question and let us know. Also, if you've tried anything, please let us know what you've tried. Every time you edit your question, it will be bumped to the top of the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File access auditing is built into Windows but must be turned on and configured.  Configuration is not trivial, however, there are [many](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070.aspx) [resources](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2008/03/use-auditing-to-track-who-deleted-your-files/) available to assist with this.  Once auditing has been enabled for certain actions they will be saved in Windows event log.